# How do I use jq to get formatted list of package identifiers

Tags: json, jq, dependency-management, yarnpkg

I'm trying to write a script that can add the package.json dependencies from one project to another one programmatically.

This is probably trivial jq, although I did search around and couldn't find anything that does this exactly.

What I ultimately want to do is this:

```
yarn add $(get-my-deps.sh)
```

And so I'm writing get-my-deps right now.

- I know the path to my package.json file
- I know that `yarn add package-name@^1.23.45 package-name-2@^2.3.4` does what I want

I figure I want to do something like:

```
jq ".dependencies | keys" package.json
//                  ^ this is where I'm stuck
```

I don't want just a list of package names, I want to convert the hash of package-name/version-range data into a string with their names and ranges, like this:

```
babel@^7.3.12 react@^16.0.0 react-dom@^16.0.0 webpack@^4.0.0
```

I think I just don't understand how the... caret works in jq. I imagine it's the conceptual equivalent of regex backreferencing.

Here's the JS code:

```js
module.exports = () => {

const package = require('./package.json')
// or, if you prefer
const FS = require('fs')
const package = FS.readFileSync('./package.json', 'utf8')

return Object.keys(package.dependencies)
// convert to array of strings: "{name}@{range}"
.reduce((modules, modName) => modules.concat(`${modName}@${package.dependencies[modName]}`), [])
// convert to single string for bash one-liner
.join(' ')

}
```

I'm sure this is a pretty trivial task for anyone who is fluent with jq, so I'm going to wait a couple days so that folks can take time to put together a good explanation.

Thanks for helping me get my head wrapped around jq.

---

Here's an example input:

```
{
    "name": "chalk",
    "version": "3.0.0",
    "description": "Terminal string styling done right",
    "license": "MIT",
    "repository": "chalk/chalk",
    "main": "source",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=8"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "xo && nyc ava && tsd",
        "bench": "matcha benchmark.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "ansi-styles": "^4.1.0",
        "supports-color": "^7.1.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ava": "^2.4.0",
        "coveralls": "^3.0.7",
        "execa": "^3.2.0",
        "import-fresh": "^3.1.0",
        "matcha": "^0.7.0",
        "nyc": "^14.1.1",
        "resolve-from": "^5.0.0",
        "tsd": "^0.7.4",
        "xo": "^0.25.3"
    }
}
```

What must be produced:

```
ansi-styles@^4.1.0 supports-color@^7.1.0
```

Comment: Apologies. I assumed everyone knows what a typical package.json looks like. I've posted an abridged version of chalk's file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close; all you need was to realize how to store keys in a variable, so that you can combine each key with its corresponding value to form a single string.

Here's how you do it:

```
.dependencies | [ keys[] as $k | "\($k)@\(.[$k])" ] | join(" ")
```

<sup>[Online demo at jqplay.org](https://jqplay.org/s/6lL9nlHLJ_)</sup>

`keys[]` expands to a stream of keys in `dependencies`; with `as $k`, we're telling jq to store each member of this stream in a variable called `$k` and make it available on the right hand side of the pipe. `"\($k)@\(.[$k])"` simply forms a string by combining `$k`, `@` and `.[$k]` (i.e: the value corresponding to `$k`). By wrapping this expression between brackets, we're storing each value it yields in an array, and by piping this array to `join(" ")`, we're joining the array elements by a space to form a single string. That's all.

Comment: That's a pretty neat idiom for recursing key-value pairs.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I came up with this. It works. But if this isn't the idiomatic way to do it, I'd welcome an improved version.

```
jq ".dependencies | to_entries | map_values( .key + \"@\" + .value ) | join(\" \")" package.json
//> "ansi-styles@^4.1.0 supports-color@^7.1.0"
```

[POC repl](https://jqterm.com/cbb1dc06b92d280d447533ed89e7271b?query=.dependencies%20%7C%20to_entries%20%7C%20map_values%28%20.key%20%2B%20%22%40%22%20%2B%20.value%20%29%20%7C%20join%28%22%20%22%29)

Comment: I'm very new to jq.

Comment: It's more about the shell, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27701642/10248678

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: I'm on MacOS, and this command will run inside an Alpine-based Docker container.

Comment: Then use single quotes for the jq command so that you don't have to backslash so much inside! `jq '.dependencies | to_entries | map_values( "\(.key)@\(.value)" ) | join(" ")' package.json`